# comparing string to words in an array

Tags: c, arrays, string, strcmp, strcpy

I got an assignment from my teacher to write a code that compares a given word to a bunch of words located in an array of strings.
If the word in the array is lexicography smaller than the word given, I need to put it inside a new array.
else, I'm moving to the next word.
for example;
given word: hello
arr=bus, alpha, world, java.
new array=bus,alpha.
I wrote a code that does that using STRCMP, but the computer throws me out when it gets to the strcpy part.
this is my code

```
char** LowerSTR(char* arr[], int size_arr, char* str, int* size_res)

size_res = 0;
char** newArr= (char**)calloc(size_arr, sizeof(char));
for (int i = 0; i < size_arr; i++)
{
    if (strcmp(str, arr[i])==1)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k <size_arr;k++)
        {
            strcpy(newArr[k], arr[i]);
        }
        size_res++;
    }
}
if (size_res == 0)
    return NULL;
else return newArr;}
```

maybe I should use STRCAT instead?

please help :\

Comment: When you say "the computer throws me out" what exactly do you mean? Is there a seg fault? What error message do you receive?

Comment: Exception thrown at 0x0102EE72 (ucrtbased.dll) in 11111.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

Answer (score 1):

In calling `strcpy` with `newArr[k]` as an argument you're dereferencing a `NULL` pointer.

Recall that we allocate `newArr` as follows:

```c
char** newArr= (char**)calloc(size_arr, sizeof(char));
```

There's actually multiple errors here. The first is that we `calloc` with `sizeof(char)` when we in fact want a region of `char*`s. So corrected<sup>1</sup> 
we have

```c
char** newArr= calloc(size_arr, sizeof(char*));
```

As we've `calloc`'d this piece of memory, all of it is zeroed. Thus when `strcpy` internally accesses `newArr[k]` (itself of type `char*`) it points to memory address 0, which is likely reversed by the OS, and in any case, not a valid address in the context of our program.

In order to resolve this, we need to allocate for each string. For instance, one might do

```c
newArr[k] = malloc(strlen(arr[i]) + 1); // The +1 is for the \0 termination character
```

the line before we `strcpy`.

You also have a bug with `size_res` as you just treat it as an `int` instead of an `int*` as you need to dereference it when you want to change or read the value to which it points.

<sup>1</sup> See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/12521158) for why I've removed the cast.

Comment: Thanks!! All the problems are gone, but im not getting the result i need.
how do i print the new array after the changes?

Answer (score 0):

You should scan `newArr` and print all strings inside, something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < *size_res; i++) // !
{
   printf("%s\n",newArr[i]);
}
```

(!) 'size_res' is passed to the function as a pointer to int,